# Grab everything between b elements with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Here is the HTML:

```
<tr class="level2">
    <td> 
        <b>word</b>
        "Text I need"
        <b>word</b>
        "Text I need"
        <b>word</b>
        "Text I need"
        <b>word</b>
        "Text I need"
        <i>blabla</>
        "Text I need"
        <b>word</b>
        "Text I need"
        <i>blabla</>
        "Text I need"
        <i>blabla</>
        <b>word</b>

    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to select each node between the `<b>` elements and then iterate through each of them later. Currently I have:

```
translations = page.xpath('//text()[preceding-sibling::b]')
```

It works fine when there is only text between `<b>` elements. However, when one or more `<i>` tags occur between the `<b>` elements, I get only the first text in the node. The remaining text in the node goes to the following node.
I want the output:

```
node 1: Text I need 
node 2: Text I need 
node 3: Text I need 
node 4: Text I need 
        Text I need 
node 5: Text I need 
        Text I need
```

This is the code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri' #parse html
require 'csv'

DATA_DIR = "words"
Dir.mkdir(DATA_DIR) unless File.exists?(DATA_DIR) # making directory
BASE_LINK = "http://dict.ibs.ee/translate.cgi?word=" 
LANGUAGE = "&language=English"
WILDCARD = "*"
SLEEP_TIME = 0.1 # sleep between web requests in seconds
counter = 1 #counter for file name
i = 1
name = "IBSwords"+"#{counter}"+".csv"

alphabet = %w[a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z]
four_letter_combinations = alphabet.product(alphabet, alphabet, alphabet).map(&:join)
#combination from 4 letters
for combination in four_letter_combinations
  begin
    i += 1
      if (i % 150000 ) == 0
        counter += 1
        name = "IBSwords"+"#{counter}"+".csv" 
      end
    sleep (SLEEP_TIME) 
    link = BASE_LINK+"about"+LANGUAGE
    page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(link)) #retry in 60 sec if no connection
  rescue StandardError=>e
    puts "#{e} No Connection, retrying..."
    sleep 60
  retry
  else 
    unless page.css('body > div > center > table > tbody > tr > td > div > center > table > tbody > tr > td > blockquote > dl > dd > b').nil?
      puts "*****************#{i} #{combination}***********"
      en_words = page.css('blockquote > dl > dd > b')
      #ee_words = page.css('blockquote > dl > dd').to_s.split(/<b>.*<\/b>/)
      ee_words = page.xpath('//text()[preceding-sibling::b]') 
      # iterating through 
      en_words.zip(ee_words).each  do |word, ee_word|
      en_word = word.text.chomp.strip
      ee_trans = ee_word.text.chomp.strip
      #en_desc = word.xpath('td[2]/node()[not(self::strong)]').text
      puts "#{en_word}"
      puts "#{ee_trans}"
      puts "*******************************"
      i += 1
      #writing to csv 
      CSV.open("words/#{name}", "ab") do |row| # write to CSV
          row << [
          en_word,
          #en_desc,
          ee_trans,
          #ee_desc
        ]
      end
    end
  end
end
end
```

Comment: If you're looking for only the text in the `td` node, why not use `page.css('td').text`?

Comment: A better description of what you want, compared to “text between `b` tags”, is “text between `b` elements”. “tags” means `<b>` and `</b>` – opening and closing tags. “Between tags” means the content of `b` elements, which is not what you want.

Comment: You see, I am also using `words = page.css('tr td b')` In every **b** tag there is a word and all the following text after that **b** tag is a translation. Later on I am mapping each translation to the word: `words.zip(translations).each  do |x, y|`

Comment: When asking a question, strip the code to its bare minimum that demonstrates the problem. Anything beyond that wastes our time helping you by confusing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reduced your HTML to be less verbose. It achieves the same thing without extra text.

I'd do it like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<tr class="level2">
    <td> 
        <b>word</b>
        "Text I need"
        <b>word</b>
        "Text I need"
        <i>blabla</i>
        "Text I need"
        <b>word</b>
        "Text I need"
        <i>blabla</i>
        "Text I need"
        <i>blabla</i>
        <b>word</b>
    </td>
</tr>
EOT

doc.search('td i').remove
```

Since the `<i>` nodes aren't needed simply strip them. The resulting `doc` looks like:

```
puts doc.to_html
# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html><body>
# >> <tr class="level2">
# >>     <td> 
# >>         <b>word</b>
# >>         "Text I need"
# >>         <b>word</b>
# >>         "Text I need"
# >>         
# >>         "Text I need"
# >>         <b>word</b>
# >>         "Text I need"
# >>         
# >>         "Text I need"
# >>         
# >>         <b>word</b>
# >> 
# >>     </td>
# >> </tr>
# >> </body></html>
```

Once the `<i>` nodes are gone it's possible to iterate over the contents of the `<td>` and process their text:

```
text = doc.at('td').children.reject { |n| n.text.strip == '' }.slice_before { |n| n.name == 'b' }.map{ |a| a.map { |n| n.text.strip }}
```

At this point `text` contains:

```
text
# => [["word", "\"Text I need\""],
#     ["word", "\"Text I need\"", "\"Text I need\""],
#     ["word", "\"Text I need\"", "\"Text I need\""],
#     ["word"]]
```

Note, there's a trailing "word", which mimics the sample HTML you gave. If you know you won't have any trailing text you want to keep, you can simply `pop` off that element. If you think there are elements that are only single items you could iterate over the list looking for singles and reject them also. How to handle it is up to you and for you to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for `xpath`-only solution, but here is the one using ruby enumerator:

```
xml.xpath('//td').children.inject({}) do |memo, node|
  case node.name
  when 'b' then memo["#{node.children.first}"] = ""
  when 'text' 
    memo["#{memo.keys.last}"] << "#{node}" unless memo.length.zero?
  else # just skip
  end 

  memo
end
```

That gives:

```
#⇒ {
#  "word 1" => "\n        \"Text I need 1\"\n        ",
#  "word 2" => "\n        \"Text I need 2\"\n        ",
#  "word 3" => "\n        \"Text I need 3\"\n        ",
#  "word 4" => "\n        \"Text I need 41\"\n        \n        \"Text I need 42\"\n        ",
#  "word 5" => "\n        \"Text I need 51\"\n        \n        \"Text I need 52\"\n        \n        ",
#  "word 6" => "\n\n    "
# }
```

Hope it might help.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I really don't know how to properly implement your code. As You can see I am trying to print EN word+ EE translation pairs (added full code )

Comment: I don’t get what the problem is. The code above produces hash, on which you might simply iterate with `.each  do |word, ee_word|` as you did.